# Searching pip in python(xy)

Tags: python, pip, pythonxy

Today I fully installed Python(xy) on my machine. Now I'm still lacking the package `sphinx-intl`, so that I was trying to install it with `pip sphinx-intl`.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the `pip.exe` in the `Python27` directory.

Where do I have to search for this program?

Comment: It is usually in `C:\PythonXX\Scripts`. Pip should come with your Python version (unless you are using an old version) so there is no need to install it.

Comment: I looked in the directory `C:\Python27\Scripts`, but there is nothing like a `pip.exe`. I installed `Python(xy)-2.7.10.0` from the download page, which already includes the Pip Installer. I'm using Windows 7 Pro. It is really a mystery to me.

Comment: You mean this download page? https://www.python.org/downloads

Comment: No. This one http://python-xy.github.io/downloads.html.

Comment: I reinstalled it again and now its there. Maybe I accidentally checked a box. How knows. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You many need to install pip. Find the instructions here -

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/